# BASH scripting, proper quoting of variable inside sed?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

This variable,
Btr="/home/BB/PL/DDr/";
is successfully echoed so I know it should be available, but none of these sed work properly.

Variants of syntax I have tried, none of which work.

1.

```
    Lg=$(echo "${Prg}" | sed 's/\(\/home\/in\/PL\/\)\(.*_Data.txt\)$/'$Btr'\2/');
```

2.

```
    Lg=$(echo "${Prg}" | sed 's/\(\/home\/in\/PL\/\)\(.*_Data.txt\)$/'${Btr}'\2/');
```

3.

```
    Lg=$(echo "${Prg}" | sed 's/\(\/home\/in\/PL\/\)\(.*_Data.txt\)$/"$Btr"\2/');
```

4.

```
    Lg=$(echo "${Prg}" | sed 's/\(\/home\/in\/PL\/\)\(.*_Data.txt\)$/"${Btr}"\2/');
```

5.

```
    Lg=$(echo "${Prg}" | sed 's/\(\/home\/in\/PL\/\)\(.*_Data.txt\)$/'"$Btr"'\2/');
```

6.

```
    Lg=$(echo "${Prg}" | sed 's/\(\/home\/in\/PL\/\)\(.*_Data.txt\)$/"'$Btr'"\2/');
```

7.

```
    Lg=$(echo "${Prg}" | sed -e "s/\(\/home\/in\/PL\/\)\(.*_Data.txt\)$/'${Btr}'\2/");
```

8.

```
    Lg=$(echo "${Prg}" | sed -e 's/\(\/home\/in\/PL\/\)\(.*_Data.txt\)$/'${Btr}'\2/');
```

Objective is to change a line like this one:

| tee -a /home/in/PL/SomeFile_Data.txt

to this:

| tee -a /home/BB/PL/DDr/SomeFile_Data.txt

Comment: Why use / as a delimiter when your pattern contains lots of slashes already? That's asking for trouble. I'd suggest you use something else, say, comma. It will make the sed invokations much more readable.

Comment: @fstd some things don't seem to work well when you don't use slashes, though.  Such as `@PATTERN@d` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @AlexejMagura that's be \@PATTERN@d (note the escaping of the first @).  Slash seesm to be special in that the escape *can* be omitted, but generally sed expects it to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@fstd's answer.   Change the delimiter.

```
  Lg=$(echo ${Prg} | sed 's,/home/in/PL/\(.*_Data\.txt\)$,'$Btr'\1,')
```

Comment: Whoa, why would choice of separator style affect functionality?  Hunh.  Anyhow, with double quotes around the whole sed, no quotes around the variable and using comma as changed seperator, this does the job.  Tried to show it in here but these comments mangle code ;(

Comment: @MountainMan it only really helps when working with a pattern that __contains__ the delimiter you're using, such as: `sed 's/\/var\/log//'` as `sed 's_/var/log__'`

Answer (score 1):

#### Without double quotes:

```
a=1
echo 'b' | sed 's/b/'$a'/'
```

#### With double quotes:

```
a=1
echo 'b' | sed "s/b/$a/"
```

#### With single quoted pattern and double quoted variable:

```
a=1
echo 'b' | sed 's/b/'"$a"'/'
```

Comment: Tried that also;sed: -e expression #1, char x: unknown option to `s'

Comment: works fine for me.  What version of sed are you using?  __NOTE__ some things may need to be escaped if you're using double quotes!

Comment: Ah, yes. One must be wary of that.  But you guys got me sorted on this one, thx again. GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)